# Unity C# Mobile Control Swipe Left Right

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine, 3d

I made a 3d game with Unity and C#. I don't know how to make a object (player) control to left and right with swipe on mobile screen.

That's my C# code:

```
    using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;

    public float forwardForce = 300f;
    public float sidewaysForce = 200f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
      rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);

      if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0.1)
      {
        rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
      }

      if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < -0.1)
      {
        rb.AddForce(-sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look on the [Mobile Touch Tutorials](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/s/mobile-touch), the [Mobile Touch Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileInput.html) and [Input.GetTouch](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html). In short: You have to get the touch, store the initial position and than compare it to current positions.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;

    public float forwardForce = 300f;
    public float sidewaysForce = 200f;

    private Vector2 initialPosition;    

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // are you sure that you want to become faster and faster?
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);

        if(Input.touchCount == 1)
        {
            touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

            if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                initialPosition = touch.position;
            } 
            else if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary)
            {
                // get the moved direction compared to the initial touch position
                var direction = touch.position - initialPosition;

                // get the signed x direction
                // if(direction.x >= 0) 1 else -1
                var signedDirection = Mathf.Sign(direction.x);

                // are you sure you want to become faster over time?
                rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * signedDirection * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Note: This always compares to the initial touch position => you don't go into the other direction until you

1. Move the touch over the initial position in the other direction
2. And since you use `AddForce` wait the same amount of time as you added force in the other direction

Maybe you should rather only compare to the previos touch position instead of comparing to the initial one:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;

    public float forwardForce = 300f;
    public float sidewaysForce = 200f;

    private Vector2 lastPosition;    

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // are you sure that you want to become faster and faster?
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);

        if(Input.touchCount == 1)
        {
            touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

            if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                lastPosition = touch.position;
            }
            if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {
                // get the moved direction compared to the initial touch position
                var direction = touch.position - lastPosition ;

                // get the signed x direction
                // if(direction.x >= 0) 1 else -1
                var signedDirection = Mathf.Sign(direction.x);

                // are you sure you want to become faster over time?
                rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * signedDirection * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);

                lastPosition = touch.position;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you still have to swipe the same amount of time ... it doesn't take the swiped distance into account. So Maybe instead you should use that:

```
// get the moved direction compared to the initial touch position
var direction = touch.position - lastPosition ;

// are you sure you want to become faster over time?
rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * direction.x * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
```

so the more you swipe the more force gets added.

Comment: `private Touch touch;` should be added before `update();` function.